# How to know that a certain boost thread has been executed in boost C++?

Tags: multithreading, boost, c++-cli

I have made a separate thread other than the main one using boost C++ library in my source code:

```
boost::thread t(&initSynthesis);
```

I want to know when this initSyntesis() function is executed ( or the thread t) so that I can make the button visible on the windows form which was initially hidden using:

```
button1->show();
```

But the problem is that I'm making thread t from the `constructor` of the form class and `initSynthesis` function is not a part of this class so I'm unable to show the button when this function is executed. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass `button1` to `initSynthesis`, and then in `initSynthesis` you can call `button1->show();`.

Note that `button1` should be passed by reference, not by value.

```
void initSynthesis(System::Windows::Forms::Button^% button1)
{
    button1->show();

    //Do something else
}

//Thread will call 'initSynthesis' with 'button1'
boost::thread t{ &initSynthesis, button1 };
```

Comment: 1. error C3699: '&' : cannot use this indirection on type 'System::Windows::Forms::Button'

Comment: 2. IntelliSense: an ordinary reference to a C++/CLI ref class or interface class is not allowed 
-These two errors are shown

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the language tag then, as it's not C++.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments on the other answer, it appears that you're using boost threads with C++/CLI. It would be *highly* appropriate to use a [.Net thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) instead.

Using .Net threads, the answer to your question is very similar to the other answer, except you don't need to pass the button explicitly. Thread methods in .Net are allowed to be instance methods without jumping through any extra hoops, so you can just access instance fields like normal.

```
public ref class MyWindow
{
    Button^ button1;

    void foo()
    {
        Thread^ t = gcnew Thread(gcnew ThreadStart(this, &MyWindow::InitSynthesis));
        t->Start();
    }

    void InitSynthesis()
    {
        // Do work

        // OK, work's done, show the "Next" button.
        this->button1->Show();
    }
}
```